# SignalR fail method not called when user identity changed

Tags: signalr

I'm using SignalR but have run into a problem. When a connection is started in one browser window and then a user logs in in another browser window the User identity is changed (this causes the error 'System.InvalidOperationException: Unrecognized user identity.  The user identity cannot change during an active SignalR connection' on the server when a method is called on the hub.

I'm using this code on the client:

```
proxy.server.analyze(content)
.done(function () {
    console.log('Success!');
})
.always(function () {
    console.log('This is always called!');
})
.fail(function (error) {
    console.log('This is never called!');
});
```

When I'm seeing errors on the server the fail function is never being called so there appears to be no way on the client to handle this problem and stop and start the connection.

So is there a "best practice" way of handling this case? How can I detect on the client that the user identity has changed in another browser window and stop and re-start the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue.

It is fixed in the next release.  Here's the issue that ended up also fixing your issue: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2106.

Lastly, in the next release (0.2.0) what will happen is the connection will throw an error and stop itself.  Therefore you'll be able to handle your case via either the error handler or you can of course you can tie into the "disconnected" event.

If you're willing to try a pre-releases you can always pull from the offical source or webstack nightly (http://www.myget.org/F/aspnetwebstacknightly/)

Comment: Hey Taylor... what can he problem here: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2618